# How to change active launch configuration in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Feeling rather dumb:  I have a C++ project, using Eclipse CDT (Eclipse 3.6, CDT 1.3.1).

I have defined more than one launch configuration: each points to a different executable within the project.  But, when I press F11 to debug, Eclipse always loads the first configuration, and I can find no way to make it launch the 2nd one instead.

Surely this deserves a menu or dialog setting somewhere?

Comment: By "launch configuration" you mean "Build configuration? If not, then what do you mean? I think that if you right-click the project -> Build Configurations -> Set Active, then F11 will launch the active one.

Comment: Figured it out myself some months ago:  on the debug-config creation dialog, you click Debug to launch the debugger.   Later, when you want to restart the debugger, F11 does it.  To change the active configuration, you have to bring up the debug-config dialog for that config and start debugging through that button.   A bit obscure, but hey.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your projects:
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Manage Configurations... > Set Active